# Using Enumeration Class

Tags: c#, class, enumeration

I'm new to C# and I'm relatively new to abstract classes and inheritance and I'm having troubles understanding how to use them.  I have this abstract enumeration class:

```
public abstract class Enumeration : IComparable
{
    public uint Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public uint MaxTemperature { get; private set; }
    public double Density { get; private set; }

    protected Enumeration()
    {

    }

    protected Enumeration(uint id, string name, uint maxTemprature, double density)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        MaxTemperature = maxTemprature;
        Density = density;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : Enumeration, 
        new()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var fields = type.GetTypeInfo().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public 
            | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        foreach (var info in fields)
        {
            var instance = new T();
            var locatedValue = info.GetValue(instance) as T;
            if (locatedValue != null)
            {
                yield return locatedValue;
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var otherValue = obj as Enumeration;
        if (otherValue == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var typeMatches = GetType().Equals(obj.GetType());
        var valueMatches = Id.Equals(otherValue.Id);
        return typeMatches && valueMatches;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        return Id.CompareTo(((Enumeration)other).Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This class is inherited by my material class:

```
    class Material : Enumeration
{
    public static readonly Material FreeSpace =
        new Material(0, "Free Space", 0, 0);

    public static readonly Material CarbonSteel =
        new Material(1, "Carbon Steel", 2500, 0.284);

    private Material()
    {
    }

    private Material(uint id, string name, uint maxTemperature, 
        double density) : base(id, name, maxTemperature, density)
    {
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Material> List()
    {
        return new[] { FreeSpace, CarbonSteel };
    }
}
```

Now I want to use these materials in my part class:

```
    class Part
{
    private Material partMaterial;

    public Part() { }

    public Material PartMaterial
    {
        set
        {
            partMaterial = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I'm stuck, how do I set a variable as one of the enumerated static objects so I can get the properties from those?

Comment: By "combo list", do you mean `ComboBox`, or `Listbox`, or `ListView`, or what?

Comment: ComboBox, sorry

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with abstraction or inheritance.  Why is that mentioned at all?

Comment: Piece of advice: `Enumeration` as used here is perhaps a contender for the "worst class name ever in the history of the world".

Comment: Enumeration is what every example of how to use this online shows, it's not hard to change that name in four locations once I get this working.  The reason why abstraction and inheritance is mentioned is because that is where the problem for me lies.  I know how to build a simple class, I know how to build a base class and inherit a class from that, and I know how to use a combo box.  What I don't understand, and was hoping to get a usable answer for, is how to set a variable as one of the enumerated static objects so I can get the properties from those.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Are you perhaps talking about using an `enum` as a source of values for a `ComboBox`?

Comment: I think that's where I'm at now. I realized I set the List method in the Material class to private which I needed public to access the enumerated values of the class. So I changed that and set the combobox's data source as the list which allows me to choose the materials and pass the material to the part. Right now they all just show up as "Material" in the combobox though so I'm looking up how I can get the name from the values in the list to display.  I think this is how to do this, but I've never used the data source property of a combobox in any language before so it's a bit foreign to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I wish I would have left the question the way it was, because in the end it was the correct way to ask the question.  But after the snide comments and down grading I changed it to what I thought was better.  The way the original question should have been answered was:

Since you are enumerating the materials class, you need a method to expose the Enumerated values of the objects.  The 
`IEnumerable<Material> List()` method should be made public to accomplish this.

You can then use `MaterialCombo.DataSource = Material.List()` to populate the combobox with the material objects and `MaterialCombo.DisplayMember = "Name";` to display the names of those objects in the combobox.

Finally, use @Oxald's answer to pass the material to your part class.

Thank you @Mark Benningfield for pointing me in the direction to search for "Using an enum to populate a combobox" which was helpful.

And Oxald for suggesting to use .SelectedItem instead of .SelectedIndex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of SelectedIndex

```
part.PartMaterial = (Material) MaterialCombo.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: This helped to get some functionality, but I'm still missing how to populate the combobox with the list value names.